# ThreadPool misses events

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool, blockingcollection

I need to queue events and execute them in parallel.

My C# code queues the events in a blocking collection and executes each event on a worker thread using the ThreadPool. However, if the events are queued with a rate of 2000 event/second or more, some events are missed. When I searched for this problem, I found out that the ThreadPool can reject some requests or hold them if no thread is available, from [this link](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3008250/application-development/understanding-thread-pools-in-c.html):

> To make matters worse, incoming requests that depend on the threads from the thread pool may be on hold or **may even be rejected** primarily because the thread pool may not have available threads with it to handle an incoming request

Note: This problem appears only when using a laptop with a Core i5, when I tried it with a Core i7, it worked correctly.

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
public static void ExecuteEvents()
{
    foreach (EventData data in blockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        switch (data.EventType)
        {
            case EventType1:
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
                {
                    Function1(data);
                });
                break;
            case EventType2:
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
                {
                    Function2(data);
                });
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Never heard of rejected workitems by the `ThreadPool`. Sounds it is something else.

Comment: What do you think of other causes? @JeroenvanLangen

Comment: have you tried adding some logging in case its decided that your mysterious disappearing ones are not eventtyp1 or 2?

Comment: Have you considered using Microsoft's Reactive Framework for doing this?

Comment: I am pretty sure they are of event type 1 or 2 as I add them in the blocking collection with their correct type. @BugFinder

Comment: I recommend you use TPL. It gives you all the infrastructure for parallel execution for free.

Comment: I've added the quote to the question and I am really curious about it.

Comment: TPL increases the CPU usage drastically.  @Sefe

Comment: You can configure TPL parameters like available CPUs and degree of parallelism. A high CPU usage is a sign that it uses your CPU ressources efficiently.

Comment: Ok, I will try that @Sefe

Comment: @Sefe The TPL isn't going to do anything to solve this problem.  In this context it would just be a wrapper around scheduling work in the thread pool, which is what this is already doing, and this wouldn't be taking advantages of any of the additional features the TPL provides, given what it's actually doing.

Comment: &Servy: TPL is more than just a wrapper. Eg. it takes into account number of CPUs, spins when appropriate etc. It would be a considerable effort to replicate that in your own solution.

Comment: @Sefe I tried to use TPL but the same behavior occurs

Comment: Then your problem probably lies somewehre else than the scheduling of your tasks.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't look like you're having a problem with the threadpool. It looks like you're having a problem with closures.

You should create a local variable within the loop first. The problem is that when the threadpool executes the action, it is referencing to the `EventData data` variable which is constantly changed. Therefore you should create a local variable first.(which will be packed in a displayclass, because the local variable is referenced from a method which is put on a list out the scope.)

```
public static void ExecuteEvents()
{
    foreach (EventData data in blockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        var local = data;
        switch (local.EventType)
        {
            case EventType1:
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
                {
                    Function1(local);
                });
                break;
            case EventType2:
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
                {
                    Function2(local);
                });
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

For more info on closures look [here](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx)

Comment: This would be true if the OP was on C# 3.0 or earlier.  This won't change a thing if they're using C# 4.0+, which, based on their comment, appears to be the case.